# Azure DevOps YAML - if statement not working through template with number/int

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Checking a version number in a yaml pipeline with an if statement and wanting to run a particular task dependent on version.  Works fine directly but I'm using templates and passing the value through it doesn't seem to work.

This works:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: TF_VERSION
  default: 1.3.3

steps:
- ${{ if lt(parameters.TF_VERSION, 1) }}:
  - powershell: Write-Host "I'm running lt 1.0"  
- ${{ if ge(parameters.TF_VERSION, 1) }}:
  - powershell: Write-Host "I'm running ge 1.0"
```

This doesn't with the first condition always returning true:

```
trigger:
- main
    
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: YAML-Templates      
      ref: refs/heads/main

variables:
- name: TF_VERSION
  value: 1.3.3

steps:
- template: if/if.yml@templates
  parameters:    
    TF_VERSION: $(TF_VERSION)
```

template:

```
parameters:
- name: TF_VERSION

steps:
- ${{ if lt(parameters.TF_VERSION, 1) }}:
  - powershell: Write-Host "I'm running lt 1.0"  
- ${{ if ge(parameters.TF_VERSION, 1) }}:
  - powershell: Write-Host "I'm running ge 1.0"
```

Anyone know why???

Comment: I updated my answer, with an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem.
I can partly solve it by adding [the mandatory type to the parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#passing-parameters) in the template:

```
parameters:
- name: TF_VERSION
  type: number

steps:
- ${{ if lt(parameters.TF_VERSION, 1) }}:
  - powershell: Write-Host "I'm running lt 1.0"  
- ${{ if ge(parameters.TF_VERSION, 1) }}:
  - powershell: Write-Host "I'm running ge 1.0"
```

[image: demo2]

The only down side seems to be that I'm not able to pass a variable from the calling YAML due to this error.

[image: not a number]

This issue can be overcome by setting the number directly in the parameter like this:

```
trigger:
- main
    
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: YAML-Templates      
      ref: refs/heads/main

steps:
- template: if/if.yml@templates
  parameters:    
    TF_VERSION: 1.5
```

Like you mentioned, 1.3.3, a version number, is still not a number.

**Alternative**

Alternatively you could go for [startsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#startswith) like so:

```
parameters:
- name: TF_VERSION

steps:
- ${{ if startsWith(parameters.TF_VERSION, '0.') }}:
  - powershell: Write-Host "I'm running 0.x"  
- ${{ if startsWith(parameters.TF_VERSION, '1.') }}:
  - powershell: Write-Host "I'm running 1.x"
```

I hope this answers the question, why it is not working and what a possible alternative is.

### Edit-2

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74846291/8843952) of Antonia Wu-MSFT's also work, the why is still a bit unclear. But I think it has to do with: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#template-expression-syntax

But to be honest, still don't understand why a type is [mandatory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#passing-parameters) according to the documentation, but not used in this case.

Comment: Sorry but neither of these work for me with "I'm running lt 1.0" being returned when passing 1.3.3.  Calling the template was never the issue.

Comment: OK @GuyWood sorry it didn't help. 
Let me rework this for you later today. There must be another explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this.  It works with 1.5 but not with 1.3.3 because that isn't a number.  That makes sense but strange how it compares them ok directly just not in the template.

Comment: That is true, 1.3.3 is still not a number. Added an alternative as well, hope that this answers the question

Comment: Thanks again @promicro.  This does the trick nicely now.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried only to change the `TF_VERSION: $(TF_VERSION)` to `TF_VERSION: ${{ variables.TF_VERSION }}` in the main yaml.

```
trigger:
- main
    
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: YAML-Templates      
      ref: refs/heads/main

variables:
- name: TF_VERSION
  value: 1.3.3

steps:
- template: /if/if.yml@templates
  parameters:    
    TF_VERSION: ${{ variables.TF_VERSION }}
```

Then run the pipeline with the template it seems work and get this:
[image]

Please kindly try whether it works on your side. And hope it could do some help:>

Comment: Tried it and like it! Therefor I updated my already submitted (and accepted) answer. Can you explain the "why" this works? It still missed the type for the template parameter, but it is stated as mandatory in the docs? Although this isn't my question, I want know for the future :-D